# Comparing CSV's and creating a new csv based on the difference

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a daily updated CSV some days there will be no change and some days they will update.
I need to track those, and update them in new CSV is there a way in python how I can do that?
For example:
csv for 14/7/2022
[image]

CSV for 15/7/2022
[image]

New csv should be created counting how many days in a week did the old csv change
Example
1st week of july if new columns are added then for 5 days the the date should be like

[image]

where 4 and 1 tells how many days in last week the csv is updated with new values

Answer (score -1):

For your first question, yes you can achieve it using an md5 checksum (on entire file  or row as needed)

Your following statements are not clear to me, please elaborate.

Comment: Like i have multiple CSVs and i want to track the modifications that happens for each file like shown in 3rd image